# Customize the sharekit for iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I want to customize the Facebook share button functionality and want to push a new viewController as soon as user share or post on the wall using iphone. I know it is possible, we need to write just 2 or 3 line of code of javaScript but not getting the code. I am using Sharekit in my app. anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the post send or shared on user's wall by FBDialogDelegate methods. In your project Expand Sharekit > Sharers > Services > Facebook > SHKFacebook.m  and find the method

`- (void)dialogDidSucceed:(FBDialog*)dialog`
This method will call when user post or share on wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to notifications, which are issued by default during ShareKit workflow. The benefit is, that you do not need to change ShareKit's code.

For preview of notifications sent by ShareKit, look at `SHKSharer.m`, delegate notification section.

The notifications to listen to are for example

```
@"SHKSendDidStartNotification"
```

or

```
@"SHKSendDidFinish"
```

etc.